# Android - Hiding CheckBoxes if value is empty

Tags: android, arraylist, android-view, android-checkbox

I'm searching for a better way to hide my CheckBoxes. There are minium 2 and maximum 5 CheckBoxes in each case (5 answer CheckBoxes and 5 solution CheckBoxes).

[image: My CheckBoxes]

I'm filling the answer Arraylist dynamically with the values of my database. Then I'm checking for each case if the list has a value. If there is a value the CheckBox gets the answertext, if not the text is null. After that I want to hide all answer Checkboxes with empty Values. In addition I have to handle the related solution CheckBoxes. This is the way of my implementation:

```
if (question.getQuestiontype() == 2) {
            cb_answer1.setText(answerList.size() >= 1 ? answerList.get(0).getAnswertext() : null);
            cb_answer2.setText(answerList.size() >= 2 ? answerList.get(1).getAnswertext() : null);
            cb_answer3.setText(answerList.size() >= 3 ? answerList.get(2).getAnswertext() : null);
            cb_answer4.setText(answerList.size() >= 4 ? answerList.get(3).getAnswertext() : null);
            cb_answer5.setText(answerList.size() >= 5 ? answerList.get(4).getAnswertext() : null);

            if (cb_answer3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                cb_answer3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                cb_answer3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (cb_answer4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (cb_answer5.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes) {
                cb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

It looks a little bit awkward and I think it is not the best way to handle this.
Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, if I'be well understood, I think you could simplify your code separing cbs logic like here:

if(question.getQuestiontype()==2)

```
{
    cb_answer1.setText(answerList.size() >= 1 ? answerList.get(0).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer2.setText(answerList.size() >= 2 ? answerList.get(1).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer3.setText(answerList.size() >= 3 ? answerList.get(2).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer4.setText(answerList.size() >= 4 ? answerList.get(3).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer5.setText(answerList.size() >= 5 ? answerList.get(4).getAnswertext() : null);

    if (cb_answer3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        cb_answer3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cb_solution3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        cb_answer3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cb_solution3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (cb_answer4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        cb_answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cb_solution4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (cb_answer5.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        cb_answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cb_solution5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes) {
        cb.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Then looking at this code you can see that you are doing the same operations on variuos answer and response cbs. So you could create a parametrized method like this:

if(question.getQuestiontype()==2) {

```
    cb_answer1.setText(answerList.size() >= 1 ? answerList.get(0).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer2.setText(answerList.size() >= 2 ? answerList.get(1).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer3.setText(answerList.size() >= 3 ? answerList.get(2).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer4.setText(answerList.size() >= 4 ? answerList.get(3).getAnswertext() : null);
    cb_answer5.setText(answerList.size() >= 5 ? answerList.get(4).getAnswertext() : null);

    this.setCheckboxVisibility(cb_answer3, cb_solution3);
    this.setCheckboxVisibility(cb_answer4, cb_solution4);
    this.setCheckboxVisibility(cb_answer5, cb_solution5);

    for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes) {
        cb.setEnabled(true);
    }
}


private void setCheckboxVisibility(Checkbox answer, Checkbox solution) {

    if (answer.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        solution.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        solution.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Then you can combine this solution with that posted by TWL

Answer (score 1):

how about an array of views?

example:

```
CheckBox[] answers = new CheckBox[] {cb_answer1, cb_answer2, cb_answer3, cb_answer4, cb_answer5};
for (int i = answerList.size(); i < answers.length; i++) {
   answers[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

feel free to expand on that!